# MacOS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) uses h/w encryption?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, encryption

I have a [LaCie 2big](https://www.lacie.com/products/product.htm?id=10584), connected via Thunderbolt 2.

When I select as a disk-partition **MacOS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)**, does that uses some type of hardware encryption or is it all software?

Comment: What are you trying to figure out in the end? In one sense all encryption is hardware since code runs on a CPU and everything is software since without programming or direction a digital computer does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this option, you'll endup with a whole disk encryption.

It uses OSX CoreStorage volume management technology and XTS-AES 128-bit encryption, so it's software.

---

Edit : As pointed Alan Shutko, [since 2011](http://www.hutsby.net/2011/08/macs-with-aes-ni.html) Intel added an [Intruction set to intel processor to do AES encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set).

Comment: Unless you have a suitably recent Intel Core processor with built-in AES, in which case the AES will be done that way. In any case, it is never done by hardware in the drive.